# WordPress instances on Amazon Lighsail virtual server throwing 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I have a new lightsail instance running wordpress, 20GB plan, running a wordpress app. When I go to the IP address in my browser, I get a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error. I tried restarting the stack, that didn't help. I tried rebooting, that didn't help. Other instances I've started up came up just fine without problems. There's no useful error message in apache logs. Not sure what the problem is, not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 0):

Dammit, typo in the IP address. Checked that thing like 5x. There goes an hour.